# Create Tikz Single arrow label text orthogonal to arrow direction

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I have this macro to create down arrows

```
\newcommand{\arrowdown}[1]{
\tikz[baseline=-1ex]{\node [draw, fill=orange, single arrow, minimum height=3.5ex, single arrow head extend=1ex, rotate=-90] {#1};}
}
```

Which gives me the following arrow

[image]

However what I want is for the label to be by the side of the arrow, written horizontally. Since the arrow is rotated by -90, I want the label text to be rotated by 0 degrees, and start to the right of the arrow itself.

EDIT: Sketch of what I want to get, except I would prefer to have that arrow styled like the one above:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rotate` rotates the whole thing, `shape border rotate` the contour. This example is more or less identical to what's done in the first example on p. 785 of the pgfmanual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\newcommand{\arrowdown}[1]{
\tikz[baseline=-1ex]{\node [draw, fill=orange, single arrow, 
minimum height=3.5ex, single arrow head extend=1ex,
shape border uses incircle,shape border rotate=-90] {#1};}
}
\begin{document}
\arrowdown{Pft}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or for the updated question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\newcommand{\arrowdown}[1]{
\tikz[baseline=-1ex]{\node [draw, fill=orange, single arrow, 
minimum height=3.5ex, single arrow head extend=1ex,
rotate=-90](arr) {}; \node[anchor=west] at ([xshift=0.5em]arr.90) {#1};}
}
\begin{document}
\arrowdown{Pft}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I've added an edit for what I precisely want- I want the label outside the arrow since my labels might be quite long.

Comment: @Venkat I added something along those lines, too. (You could, of course, just add the arrow, use an appropriate `baseline` and write the text right of the `tikzpicture`.)